# R factors and df

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

New to R, 
trying to iterate through a DF and see if the data type of the row is empty ('') 
If so, I would like to add a factor and if not then do nothing.

My expected output is for df$data_type[i] to contain  25 Levels: BIGINT BOOLEAN BYTEINT CHAR DATE DATETIME DECIMAL DOUBLE FLOAT INT NUMBER NUMERIC OBJECT REAL SMALLINT STRING ... VARIANT. I am using this DF to render a Rhandsontable and I need the empty data type cols to have a drop down which contains the items in the factor. The dropdown will be used for users to select only a valid data type from the data_type_vals.

sample df vals

```
               logical_name physical_name data_type length
1     AGENT PERIPHERAL NAME  AGT_PRPHL_NM   VARCHAR   32.0
2 AGENT SCHEDULE IDENTIFIER   AGT_SCHD_ID    NUMBER   <NA>
3                  DUE DATE        DUE_DT  



foo <- function(df){
  data_type_vals <- c("BIGINT", "BOOLEAN", "BYTEINT", "CHAR", "DATE", "DATETIME", "DECIMAL", "DOUBLE", "FLOAT", "INT", "NUMBER", "NUMERIC", "OBJECT", "REAL", "SMALLINT", "STRING", "TEXT", "TIME", "TIMESTAMP", "TIMESTAMP_LTZ", "TIMESTAMP_NTZ", "TIMESTAMP_TZ", "VARBINARY", "VARCHAR", "VARIANT")
    df <- mutate_all(df, funs(toupper))

dput(head(df))

    if(nrow(df)>=1){
      for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
        if(df$data_type[i] == ''){
#this line is not working
          df$data_type[i] <- factor('', levels = data_type_vals)   
#this works but replaces all 
df$data_type <- factor('', levels = data_type_vals)   
        }
      }
    }
   dput(head(df))    
}
```

[Rhandsontable image/the red box should be a dropdown with the factor values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3BqU.png)

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: @rNewb23: Review [edit]. You should a) replace your print output with `dput(head(your_df))` and b) copy your comment to the question body and then delete the comment. It's not clear in it current form. And c) explain what the business is with a "dropdown".

Comment: `dput(head(df))` gives a copy/pasteable version of the first few rows of your data -- it's the best way to share sample data with us. Change the text of you function from `dput(head(df))` back to `print(df)`. Then in your R session enter `dput(head(df))` into the console and paste the result into your question---replacing (or augmenting) the "sample df values" you have.

Comment: And, by "the factor values", do you mean the string `"FACTOR"`? After adding the sample data from `dput`, please show exactly what you want the output to be for the sample input.

Comment: It doesn't  make sense to "have df$data_type[i] contain levels". Levels of a factor are associated with the whole vector, not with a particular element---that is those levels could be for `df$data_type`, but saying they need to be for `df$data_type[i]` is confusing.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing data, but I would try (a) converting to character first, `df$data_type = as.character(df$data_type)`, then (b) making any row-edits you want, perhaps `df$data_type[df_data_type == ""] = NA` - replacing blanks (not a factor level in you list) with missing values, and finally (c) converting to a factor with the levels you want: `df$data_type = factor(df$data_type, levels = data_type_vals )`